# Changing Keys of a subgraph in apollo federation

Tags: apollo, graphql-java, apollo-federation, netflix-dgs

I have two subgraphs that contribute to a supergraph by following apollo federation 2.0. One of the subgraph defines a type Payment which has a field bill. The subgraph that defines the Payment type has only id of the bill and other fields in the bill type are resolved by the other subgraph. The key of the type bill is an id field. I want to change the key of the type bill to composite key containing two fields i.e. id and a new field called source. What changes I would need to make and how can I ensure that the composition by apollo router works fine, if changes in one subgraph would be deployed and then after sometime the changes in another subgraph would be deployed?